# LESS generating empty folders in lieu of CSS files

Tags: playframework, less, sbt

I am using SBT 0.13.5 with LESS and sometimes LESS generates the CSS files properly but other times for no apparent reason at all it generates empty folders with the same name, (e.g. 'somestylesheet.min.css/').  LESS build settings:

```
  includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less",
  excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less",
  LessKeys.compress in Assets := true
```

The empty folders obviously breaks the build.  Why would this plugin ever generate empty folders instead of the CSS files?  It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: do you have any error warning? maybe you less code is broken

Comment: I enabled LESS verbosity, no errors, and the second time it generated the CSS files as expected.  So it appears to be an intermittent problem difficult to reproduce.  So far today it has flipped back and forth like this about 4 times.